# Ubuntu - Apache: Passenger not launching Rails app at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache. I try to start my rails application with Phusion Passeger. But the application is not started at all, I get HTML 403 "You don't have permission to access /kainji/ on this server" if I enter the URL: http://poyry.wo.local/kainji and the only log in `other_vhosts_access.log`:

```
poyry.wo.local:80 127.0.0.1 - - [13/Dec/2018:15:19:28 +0100] "GET /kainji/ HTTP/1.1" 403 513 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36" 2265
```

I have the following file in sites-available directory linked into sites-enabled directory:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName poyry.wo.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/rails

  <Directory /var/www/html/dev/rails>
    Options -Indexes
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  PassengerBaseURI /kainji
  <Directory /var/www/html/dev/rails/v2p0-kanji/public>
    RailsEnv    development
    Options     -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If I remove the link I get HTML 404: "The requested URL /kainji was not found on this server." what is correct.

In Apache error log I see, that Passenger was started:

```
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.8778 4321/7efdbb745780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.8885 4324/7f0b49b28780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.8886 4324/7f0b49b28780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.8908 4324/7f0b49b28780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 4324
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.9045 4356/7fd543c3b780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2018-12-12 14:17:41.9051 4356/7fd543c3b780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 4356
[Wed Dec 12 14:17:42.201857 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 4318] AH01909: centos1.tibi1959.hu:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Dec 12 14:17:42.209447 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4318] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Phusion_Passenger/5.0.29 OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Dec 12 14:17:42.209484 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4318] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Also the validating of the passenger installation is OK:

```
$ /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
What would you like to validate?
Use <space> to select.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

   ⬢  Passenger itself
 ‣ ⬢  Apache

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Checking whether there are multiple Apache installations...
Only a single installation detected. This is good.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓
 * Checking whether Apache is installed... ✓
 * Checking whether the Passenger module is correctly configured in Apache... ✓

Everything looks good. :-)
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From a first look, I would guess that the issue is caused by the static file service overriding the application.

The 403 error is due to the fact that directory listings are disabled and there's no index.html file to display.

You might want to change the way you set up the static file service, so the url requires the "public" folder name. This way, you could set the application server to route to the `/kainji` path.

Maybe something like:

```

  ServerName poyry.wo.local
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev/rails/kainji/public

PassengerBaseURI /kainji
  
    RailsEnv    development
    Options     -MultiViews
  

```